# printing the nodes in linked list in c

Tags: c, struct, printing, insert, linked-list

here is  a program which  inserting 2 names 2 paths and 2 duration s into linked list (struct of linked lists) , printing them and swapping between them when the duration of the first node is 8. 
but when the program printing the nodes its prints from all of the nodes the name and the path of the last node 
please help me

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Frame
{
    char            *name;
    unsigned int    duration;
    char            *path;  // may change to FILE*
}*n3;

typedef struct Frame frame_t;

struct Link
{
    frame_t *frame;
    struct Link *next;
}*n ;

typedef struct Link link_t;

struct Link* insert(struct Link *n3);
void print(struct Link* head, int flag);
void swap(struct Link **head, int value);

#define MAX_PATH_SIZE (256)
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE (50)

int main()
{
    struct Link* head = NULL;
    int flag = 0;
    int num = 0;
    char namearray[MAX_NAME_SIZE] = { 0 };
    char patharray[MAX_PATH_SIZE] = { 0 };
    printf("1\n");
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a number you want to insert - ");
        scanf("%d", &num);
        printf("\nEnter the name -  ");
        scanf("%s", &namearray);
        printf("\nEnter the path - ");
        scanf("%s", &patharray);
        printf("\n");
        head = insert(head,num,namearray,patharray);
    }
    print(head, flag);
    swap(&head, 8);


    printf("1\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

struct Link *insert(struct Link *p, int n, char namearray[MAX_NAME_SIZE], char patharray[MAX_PATH_SIZE]) //insert func
{
    struct node *temp;
    if (p == NULL) //if the node is empty
    {
        p = (struct Link *)malloc(sizeof(struct Link)); //gives memory to the node
        p->frame = (struct Frame *)malloc(sizeof(struct Frame));
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The number added to the end of the list\n");
        }
        p->frame->duration = n; //its runing untill the node item is NULL
        p->frame->name = namearray;
        p->frame->path = patharray;
        p->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        p->next = insert(p->next, n , namearray , patharray);/* the while loop replaced by
                                     recursive call */
    }
    return (p);
}

void print(struct Link* head , int flag)//print func
{
    if (head == NULL && flag == 0) //if the node is empty
    {
        printf("The list is empty\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (head == NULL && flag != 0) //if the node isnt empty but we are in the NULL (last) item of the node
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("the nodes of the list printed\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("%d  ", head->frame->duration);//prints the currect item
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s  ", head->frame->name);//prints the currect item
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s  ", head->frame->path);//prints the currect item
    printf("\n");
    print(head->next, ++flag);//calls the func recursevly
    return 1;
}

void swap(struct Link **head, int value)
{
    while (*head && (*head)->frame->duration != value)
    {
        head = (*head)->next;
    }

    if (*head && (*head)->next)
    {
        struct list *next = (*head)->next->next;
        (*head)->next->next = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        (*head)->next->next = next;
    }
}
```

here is the print : 
[the print of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRl9Q.png)

Comment: `p->frame->name = namearray;` --> `p->frame->name = strdup(namearray);` ditto.

Comment: ...and `free` all dynamic allocated vars (`malloc`/`strdup` )

Comment: also `struct Link* insert(struct Link *n3);` bad prototype.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY        i tried and it showed me a error :Error 4 error C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details. c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\projecterino\projecterino\01.c 74 1 projecterino

Comment: `char *strdup(const char *str){ char *dup = malloc(strlen(str)+1); if(dup)  strcpy(dup, str);  return dup;}`

Comment: also `head = (*head)->next;` and `return 1;`(void function)  are wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ty its working